# Adding .NET liblaries to Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

How to add a library for Windows to cross-platform Xamarin project in Visual Studio?

Example, we have some 3rd party service with API and DLL binaries for this API. The service provides DLL for `WP`, `Android`, `iOS` and `.NET`, but not for `Xamarin`. Can I use it for `Xamarin.Android` и `Xamarin.iOS`?

I have tried to connect `WP` or `.NET` DLL to the projects, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar.

I created a `libs` folder under my Droid project and placed the Android-specific libraries in there.

I then added the DLL's to my project (using the Add Files option) and, this is important, changed the Build action to EmbeddedResource.

From there, I could access the packages as expected and work with the library.